# bathroom exhaust fan doesn't work

Tags: electrical

Bathroom exhaust fan stopped working. Wall switch is dual --one for light and other for fan. Voltage at light switch is 125VAC but voltage at fan switch (measured bare wires) was only 16VAC! My guess is an in-the-wall electrical problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you measure the voltage across the fan switch with the fan ON and report back to us?

Answer (score 1):

The fan was the problem. I measured voltage at the fan and it was 125. Experience has told me to look for the sample explanation first. I started with the wall switch. Wrong. I should have went to the fan first. Replacement was simple. I didn't have to remove the casing, only the fan which was a Nutone. I found it at Home Depot...Lowes did not have it.

Next problem I have I will think about it more before I actually do anything. Perhaps my advanced age (77) has blurred my thought processes.

Comment: I think it is more likely that your advanced age is what enabled you to solve the problem at all.